# implicit declaration of function 'wiringPilSR'

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, geany, wiringpi, implicit-declaration

I'm trying to attach an interrupt to a pin using wiringPI's `wiringPilSR`. My code looks like this:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int inPin = 3;

void myInterrupt();

int main(vodi){
    wiringPilSetupGpio();
    pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
    wiringPilSR(inPin, INT_EDGE_RISING, &myInterrupt);
    while(1){
        printf("Cycle repeated\n");
        delay(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}

void myInterrupt(){
    printf("Interrupted");
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build the code in Geany, I get a warning "`implicit declaration of function 'wiringPilSR'`" and error "`undefined reference to 'wiringPilSR'`". I have set the build commands as shown in this [tutorial on sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-gpio)

Comment: What is the definition of `wiringPilSR`?

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `wiringPilSR` isn't spelled with a lowercase `L (l)`, instead its 9th character is an uppercase `i (I)`

There goes one hour for figuring it out

Comment: interrupt service routine... :D